# Plotting "large" image with points with matplotlib - MemoryError

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to plot an image of 3193 x 3293 pixels with 1502 points.
When running in a smaller image and less points (934,722 pixels and 60 points), everything runs perfectly.

I wrote like this:

```
# I am just giving the general characteristics of the data;    
img = numpy.ndarray, dtype = uint8, shape = (3193,3293) 
points = numpy.ndarray, dtype = int32, shape = (1502,2)

plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.gray_r)
plt.autoscale(False)
plt.plot(points[:, 1], points[:, 0], 'r.', markersize = 15)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Is there any other way to do this without using that much memory?

Thanks for the attention.